# What is the use of 'Attach Tag' in Mantis

Tags: mantis

I am reporting issue at that time it shows add 'Attach Tag'
On Edit or view mode i cannot see tag label anywhere.

So what is the use of tag in mantis ?

Answer (score 0):

The use is the same as tags on stackexchange.  It allows you to categorize your reports in a more flexible way than category, as you can attach more than one tag to a bug.  The tags are listed in the detailed view of bug details (view.php).

We use it for tagging issues that were found as part of our formal QC checking, as we can then filter on the tags to generate reports, while the category had a pre-existing use to define what feature of the product the issue is affecting.